# How to conditionally filter artifacts using "needs" directive

Tags: gitlab-ci

I have a job that publishes a large artifact and also saves its CI_JOB_ID to a dotenv.  My release job uses the BUILD_JOB_ID from the dotenv to reference the large file from a known location.  In the arrangement below, the needs declaration is broad and executes the download of all artifacts.  Is there a way to configure the needs block to conditionally download so I can avoid the overhead of downloading the large file?  NOTE: These jobs are not guaranteed to run on the same builder.

```
build:
  stage: build
  script:
    - echo "BUILD_JOB_ID=$CI_JOB_ID" >> vars.env
  artifacts:
    expire_in: never
    paths:
      - large_file
    reports:
      dotenv: vars.env

release:
  stage: release
  needs:
    - job: build
      artifacts: true
  script:
    - 'echo BUILD_JOB_ID: ${BUILD_JOB_ID}'
  release:
    assets:
      links:
        - name: 'Large File'
          url: '<URL USING BUILD_JOB_ID>'
```

I have looked into using cache to store the dotenv but that apparently does not support the cross-builder requirement

Comment: You could have 2 separate release jobs. Repetition can be avoided by using hidden jobs the `extends` keyword.

Comment: The logic can be in the `script` section and the API can be used to download the artifact

Comment: @RaglandAsir - wrt 2 release jobs, i have only one artifact to release, the large file.  the dotenv artifact is only a means to get the job ID of the build job.  on the idea of using the script, are you saying use the REST API to download the artifact instead of baked in artifact sharing?